# Display database results in Django template when hyperlink is clicked on that template

Tags: python, django

I have a list of items displayed on a template, with a link "View details" placed beside each item name. When the link is clicked, some details about that item should be fetched from the database and displayed in another section **below** the list, **not** in another template. I googled for possible tutorials on this, but couldn't really find any. Can this be done with Django? If so, it would be nice to get some pointers on how to do so.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

I have two solutions:

1. Render the result in a hidden div that you make visible when the user click the "View details" link

Example (from jQuery):

```
<button>View details</button>
<p style="display: none">Hidden Database results rendered by Django template</p>

<script>
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( "p" ).show( "slow" );
});
</script>
```

2. A more complex solution (but most popular), when clicking on the link it would trigger a Javascript event that calls your server through Ajax and render the content in your page. (You can find example here: http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: In my case,the information should be fetched from the database only when the user clicks on "View details" of any item. For the first solution, if I am not wrong, the information would have to be present beforehand, i.e. before the link is clicked.

Comment: The second solution is the better one, I think. Thanks for the information, I'll try it out!

Comment: Yes indeed. Ajax would be the way to go. Check this link to get an introduction to Ajax with jQuery: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp. Next you will have to create a new view in Django that will only return the database record instead of rendering a whole template.